# Problem with 10.04 start at my notebook after updating

Tags: 10.04, keyboard

At my notebook I use UBUNTU 10.04
after regular updating I have got version
  `...37`
and yesterday I update the system to the version `...38`

Every day I switch off my notebook
and for the last 2 version I have got the following problem:

- when I switch on the notebook I must type the password    and very
  often my keyboard is not active now ! i.e. I cannot type password
- click RESTART does not help - the same situation
- when I shout down it - it helps but yesterday I had to do it 5 times
  before I could type password

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you mean Linux kernel, something like

`Linux YOURHOST 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 20:35:14 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux`

with version 37.

Did you remove the old kernels? I guess you're using grub. Does it silently boot up, or do you have an interception moment? If so, hit the  <kbd>↓</kbd> key in grub, and move to version -36, as a first workaround, and boot the old version, until the problem is fixed.

- Make a bug report [at bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/)
- Read the [LKML (Linux kernel mailing list)](https://lkml.org/) for the topic.
- Read the new announcements [or comments for new kernels](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Linux-3-3-goes-into-testing-1418516.html).